# If condition in Embedded Sql

Tags: sql, database, embedded-sql

Here is a part code form my embedded SQL program

```
EXEC SQL IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE bool_condition)
BEGIN
...
END;
```

It gives the error

> An unexpected token "IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM  table_name " was found
>   following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".   Expected tokens may include: 
>   "".   SQLSTATE=42601

Can anyone tell what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE bool_condition)
EXEC SQL
ELSE
' do something
```